# In ASP.Net can I call a user controls WebMethod using Javascript and PageMethods?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx, pagemethods

It's saying PageMethods is undefined.

Comment: Take a look at this article - http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031704-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You definitely can. Just make sure that the WebMethod has been declared as `public static`, you have referred it using the proper namespace, and `EnablePageMethods` property of the `ScriptManager` is set to `true`.

Comment: From what I read elsewhere, the WebMethod must be in the aspx file. It cannot be in an ascx.